# ESP8266 Connection with WPA2-PEAP Enterprise Network

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, wifi

I am trying to connect my nodemcu 12E module to WPA2-entrprise network but not able to connect.

I had gone through the Espressif Forum and GitHub but still not able to resolve my problem.

here is the code I am using

```
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include<EEPROM.h>
extern "C" {
#include "user_interface.h"

#include "wpa2_enterprise.h"
#include "c_types.h"
}

// SSID to connect to
char ssid[] = "TEST";
char wlpasswd[] = "";
char username[] = "test@test.local";
char password[] = "test1234";

#define addr_username 0x0000
#define addr_password 0x007F
#define addr_certificate 0x00FF

unsigned char ca_cert[] = { 
  0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x42, 0x45, 0x47, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x20, 0x43, 0x45, 0x52, 0x54, 0x49, 
  0x46, 0x49, 0x43, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x31, 0x37, 0x61, 0x61, 
  0x31, 0x33, 0x62, 0x62, 0x37, 0x31, 0x33, 0x61, 0x37, 0x62, 0x34, 0x36, 0x66, 0x39, 0x66, 0x63, 
  0x61, 0x37, 0x64, 0x62, 0x61, 0x31, 0x30, 0x32, 0x61, 0x33, 0x35, 0x63, 0x65, 0x33, 0x36, 0x38, 
  0x31, 0x39, 0x31, 0x33, 0x0a, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0x20, 0x43, 0x45, 
  0x52, 0x54, 0x49, 0x46, 0x49, 0x43, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x00,
};


void setup() {

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.printf("SDK version: %s\n", system_get_sdk_version());
  Serial.printf("Free Heap: %4d\n",ESP.getFreeHeap());

  // Setting ESP into STATION mode only (no AP mode or dual mode)

  // Clean up to be sure no old data is still inside
  wifi_station_clear_cert_key();
  wifi_station_clear_enterprise_ca_cert();
  wifi_station_set_wpa2_enterprise_auth(1);


  wifi_station_set_enterprise_username((uint8*)username, strlen(username));
  wifi_station_set_enterprise_password((uint8*)password, strlen((char*)password));
  wifi_station_set_enterprise_ca_cert(ca_cert, sizeof(ca_cert));

  WiFi.begin(ssid);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");


    delay(100);
  }

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {

}
```

Here are the logs I am getting

```
SDK version: 2.2.2-dev(38a443e)
Free Heap: 47672
WPA2 ENTERPRISE VERSION: [v2.0] enable
scandone
.............................scandone
state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
.state: 2 -> 3 (0)
state: 3 -> 5 (10)
add 0
aid 1
cnt 
...................................................................................................pm open,type:2 0
........................................................................................................................................................................................................state: 5 -> 0 (2)
rm 0
pm close 7
reconnect
.scandone
state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
state: 2 -> 3 (0)
.state: 3 -> 5 (10)
add 0
aid 1
cnt 
...................................................................................................pm open,type:2 0
........................................................................................................................................................................................................state: 5 -> 0 (2)
rm 0
pm close 7
reconnect
.scandone
state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
.state: 2 -> 3 (0)
state: 3 -> 5 (10)
add 0
aid 1
cnt 
...................................................................................................pm open,type:2 0
........................................................................................................................................................................................................state: 5 -> 0 (2)
rm 0
pm close 7
reconnect
.scandone
state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
state: 2 -> 3 (0)
state: 3 -> 5 (10)
add 0
aid 1
cnt 
....................................................................................................pm open,type:2 0
........................................................................................................................................................................................................state: 5 -> 0 (2)
rm 0
pm close 7
reconnect
.scandone
state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
state: 2 -> 3 (0)
state: 3 -> 5 (10)
add 0
aid 1
cnt 
....................................................................................................pm open,type:2 0
........................................................................................................................................................................................................state: 5 -> 0 (2)
```

Any help in this?